# Run Google Cardboard application on (Linux) server

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

Is there any way to have the Google Cardboard Plugin in Unity on PC or Mac platform?

I would like to render to texture and then send the image over the network to a mobile device.

Any pointers in how I might achieve this? Or any pointers to why it will not work?

Comment: What type of frame rates are you looking for to the mobile device? This will influence the direction and complexity of your project.

Comment: Why do you think that is relevant for the direction of the project? I would expect the framerates to depend on the hardware setup / network bandwidth.

Comment: If for example you don’t care about streaming at all you could go with an image based approach which is simple but would be limited to a few frames a second. If you need streaming then you are going to be performing real-time video encoding and streaming which is going to be a lot more complicated and have a lot more performance considerations.